# thumbnails are more bigger respect to the original image

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, imagemagick, thumbnails

i have a worpdress website where the images are most important part of it, so i have found a solution to prevent the compression of images from wordpress when upload images (wordpress make a compression of 90/100 when upload a image through
image uploader), because i want a better image quality.

this is the filter that i used:

```
add_filter( 'jpeg_quality', create_function( '', 'return 100;' ) );
```

so it's work, but i see a problem, when upload a image with example the size of 150 kb, the default thumbnails of wordpress (medium,large) are more bigger (300kb) than original image

why this ?

Comment: Most likely because you are uploading images that were saved using a lower quality setting, and now the quality gets “blown up” due to your settings. // Don’t choose a JPEG quality of 100, that is too much for most use cases. Experiment with value in the 90s range ...

Comment: thanks for reply, i tried different image type , but the problem are all same, i tried also a 90 range instead 100, but the problem persist

Comment: You need to find a compromise between image quality and file sizes - if you want better quality, you’ll get bigger files. That your original image was smaller in file size doesn’t really matter here - WP creates _new_ images for all the different (thumbnail) sizes. You specify higher quality, you get bigger file sizes. That’s just how it works.

Comment: the original image are bigger in pixel respect  the "medium "and "large" image size , so it's impossible that images with less resolution(px) are more bigger(kb) respect original images

Comment: No, that is not impossible - but in fact rather probable and likely (plus confirmed by the results you’re seeing), _because_ you increased the quality of the _encoding_ process. Again: This is a _new_ image, that has rather little relation to the “original” you upload. Encoding a low-quality image again _in high quality_ will result in larger file sizes, simple as that.